# How to remove javascript functions for IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, internet-explorer-7

I have a menu system that runs perfect in all main browser apart from IE7, the animation effect works but the positioning is off, think it has something to do with the maths and how IE7 does its margins/padding etc.

I have set up a 'static' menu for IE7 and I want to swap it out for the javascript one.

Here is my code for the menu:

```
<div id="topmenu">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
    <div id="ie-cont">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/beez5/javascript/script.js">       </script>
    <div id="slide"></div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- IE7 static menu -->
  <!--[if IE 7]>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#ie-cont').remove();
</script>
  <div id="highlight"></div>
    <?php  
switch ($parentmenu) {
case 101 : echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('highlight').className = 'home';</script>";
break;
case 103 : echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('highlight').className = 'about';</script>";
break;
case 106 :
case 165 :
case 166 :
case 167 :
case 168 : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('highlight').className = 'services';</script>";
break;
case 161 : echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('highlight').className = 'test';</script>";
break;
case 104 :
case 102 : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('highlight').className = 'contact';</script>";
}
?>  
<![endif]-->
```

I can remove the #slide div or append it but the javascript file keeps kicking out an error as it is looking for the #slide div but even moving it into a div with the #slide div and removing it doesn't seem to work.  Any suggestions on how I can unload the javascript file when the visitor is viewing in IE7 (I know there wont be too many about but contractually I have to support it!)

I've added the javascript code below:

```
var menuSlider=function(){
var m,e,g,s,q,i; e=[]; q=8; i=8;
return{
    init:function(j,k){
        m=document.getElementById(j); e=m.getElementsByTagName('li');
        var i,l,w,p; i=0; l=e.length;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var c,v; c=e[i]; v=c.value; if(v==1){s=c; w=c.offsetWidth; p=c.offsetLeft}
            c.onmouseover=function(){menuSlider.mo(this)}; c.onmouseout=function(){menuSlider.mo(s)};
        }
        g=document.getElementById(k); g.style.width=w+'px'; g.style.left=p+'px';
    },
    mo:function(d){
        clearInterval(m.tm);
        var el,ew; el=parseInt(d.offsetLeft); ew=parseInt(d.offsetWidth);
        m.tm=setInterval(function(){menuSlider.mv(el,ew)},i);
    },
    mv:function(el,ew){
        var l,w; l=parseInt(g.offsetLeft); w=parseInt(g.offsetWidth);
        if(l!=el||w!=ew){
            if(l!=el){var ld,lr,li; ld=(l>el)?-1:1; lr=Math.abs(el-l);     li=(lr<q)?ld*lr:ld*q; g.style.left=(l+li)+'px'}
            if(w!=ew){var wd,wr,wi; wd=(w>ew)?-1:1; wr=Math.abs(ew-w);     wi=(wr<q)?wd*wr:wd*q; g.style.width=(w+wi)+'px'}
        }else{clearInterval(m.tm)}
}};}();
```

Comment: instead of unloading it, dont load it in the first place if it is IE7

Answer (score 0):

If your script.js references #slide, it will error.  you aren't showing the content of script.js, so it's hard to say...  if you have your initialization in $(document).ready(function(){...}) or $(function(){...}) it should be fine.

Comment: the initialisation of the jquery remove or the javascript call?

Answer (score 0):

conditional comments are the way to go.  Ensure your menu initialization also falls on the correct side of the conditional comments.